# Download USGS satellite images of a city only

Tags: landsat, usgs

I need to download the satellite images of a city for land change detection. Specifically I need to show urbanization trends and predict the future expansion. Now I can't seem to download just the required tile. Insted USGS Earth Explorer is showing the downloadable area that is exceeding my required area or is missing it.

Comment: Where is the location are you looking at ?

Comment: It's in Pakistan. I realized that there is no way other than mosaicing the tiles in case your required are is distributed on multiple images.

Comment: what software are you using ?

Comment: @PROBERT I am using ArcGIS 10.1. Images being downloaded in BDA of USGS. Now I am not sure if the images once downloaded would be useful for the land change detection. I am downloading from the dataset L7 ETM+ SLC Off

Comment: Yes but you should use Landsat 8 because you might see black stripes on the Landsat 7 which might prevent you from see it or if you decide to perform spatial analysis work...I'd go for Landsat 8 or any other satellites .

Comment: Yes just witnessed the black stripes all over the image of Landsat 7. I also need ten year old Landsat image for the location which isn't available with the landsat 8. Should I use the Landsat 1 MSS  for the purpose?

Comment: Don't know how will Landsat 1 MSS will work because I have never use it. I'd google it further.

Comment: try http://libra.developmentseed.org/ for locating and downloading